# Java Functional Programming: creating a map of functions

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8

I have a context map, which stores a list sorted in default order.

```
Map<String,Object> context = new HashMap<String,Object>();
context.put("list_all_content_default",getAllContentSortedDefault());
```

where getAllContentSortedDefault() returns a List by sorted in default order.

Now, I want to store the same list, in two different orders, lets say by creation date as well.

**It is not possible for my clients to retrieve the list and then sort it.**

So I have an option to populate the same context map twice with different key

```
context.put("list_all_content_createdate",getAllContentSortedCreateDate());
```

But this would mean, storing the same elements in context twice with different keys.

Is it possible in Java 8 to store references of methods in a Map, which can be invoked on call.
e.g. something like

```
    context.put("list_all_content_createdate",{
List<Contents> all_contents =  (List<Contents>)context.get("list_all_content_default");

return Collections.sort(all_contents, new ContentComparatorByCreateDate(); 
});
```

This would help me save memory , and would create desired sort behaviour.

Comment: IMHO you can simply store the Java 8 defined function interfaces e.g. `BiFunction`, `Predicate` etc. In case you have multiple presentations of them why not just define your custom super interface.

Comment: @AlexSuo Your suggestions sound promising, unfortunately I am very new to this, can you help me with a dummy code?

Comment: Try ```Collections.sort(context.get("list_all_content_createdate"), new ContextComparatorByCreateDate());```.  No Stream required.

Comment: @MohitKanwar Just posted as an answer. See if that solves the problem for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that's certainly possible. It sounds as though you just need a `Comparator` passed to your function which you can then sort by. I would suggest returning a `Stream` rather than a `List` if possible - then you can sort it yourself.

I'm assuming that your map needs to store multiple lists and the caller passes a key to specify the one they want. If you only have one list then you obviously don't need the map.

```
Map<String,List<Content>> contents = new HashMap<>();
contents.put("first", getMyContents());

public Stream<Content> getMySortedContent(Comparator comparator) {
    return contents.get("first").sorted(comparator);
}
```

If you really just have one list and you want to store the comparators in your map:

```
Map<String,Comparator<Content>> comparatorMap = new HashMap<>();
comparatorMap.put("byCreateDate", Comparator.comparingBy(Content::getData));
comparatorMap.put("byName", Comparator.comparingBy(Content::getName));

public Stream<Content> getSortedContent(String comparatorKey) {
    return getContentList().stream()
        .sorted(comparatorMap.get(comparatorKey));
}
```

Finally, if you really want to have a map to methods that retrieve a sorted list then you can certainly do that as well:

```
Map<String,Supplier<List<Content>>> supplierMap = new HashMap<>();
supplierMap.put("unsorted", this::unsortedList);
supplierMap.put("sorted_by_date" this::sortedByDate);

public List<Content> getContents(String supplierKey) {
    return supplierMap.get(supplierKey).get();
}

private List<Content> unsortedList() {
    return contentsList;
}

private List<Content> sortedByDate() {
    Collections.sort(contentsList, Comparator.comparingBy(Content::getDate));
    return contentsList;
}
```

I don't like the final approach much.

Let me know if any of that is confusing you and I'll add further explanation.

Comment: I guess the second approach suggested by you should work for me. Let me try that and then I will revert.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it's possible. You need to create a map then short by any properties by passing Comparator for that.

```
Stream<Map.Entry<K,V>> sorted = map.entrySet().stream()
                                   .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(comparator));
```

Answer (score 2):

Java 8 defines each and every possible function as an interface in `java.util.function` package. So essentially what you need to do is just have a map of those function interfaces e.g.

```
Map<String, List<BiFunction>> myFunctionMap;

List<BiFunction> list;
list.add(new MyClassImplementingFunctionalInterface());

myFunctionMap.put('ABC', list);
```

To store all those variables. If you want the same function to be comparable at the same time, you can freely create a super interface extending from both `Comparable` and your function interfaces.

However, this only applies if you have 1 type of the functions in the map. If it's possible you have multiple types of functions, I reckon you need to write your own interfaces and define the methods.

NOTE: When you do things like

```
Collection<Integer> c = new ArrayList<Integer>();
c.forEach((i) -> { System.out.println(i); } );
```

Essentially you defined an anoymous object extending `java.util.function.Consumer<Integer>` interface. That's why you can just put such objects into the map.

Answer (score 0):

Providing you one working dummy example related to your problem.

```
// helper map class which contains your collection.
class CustomSortMap extends HashMap<String, Object> {

    // Single collection object is being used.
    List<Student> studentList;

    public CustomSortMap(List<Student> studentList) {
        this.studentList = studentList;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Student> get(Object key) {
        Comparator<Student> sortType = (Comparator<Student>) super.get(key);
        Collections.sort(studentList, sortType);
        return studentList;
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
        list.add(new Student(2, "dheeraj"));
        list.add(new Student(1, "shivam"));
        list.add(new Student(3, "sandeep"));
        list.add(new Student(5, "abhay"));
        list.add(new Student(4, "rohit"));

        // printing initial collection.
        printCollection(list);

        // Instantiating helper map class and passing your collection.
        CustomSortMap customMap = new CustomSortMap(list);

        // sorting collection on the basis of id.
        customMap.put("ID", new Comparator<Student>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Student stu1, Student stu2) {
                return stu1.getId().compareTo(stu2.getId());
            }
        });
        printCollection((Collection<Student>) customMap.get("ID"));

        // sorting collection on the basis of name.
        customMap.put("NAME", new Comparator<Student>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Student stu1, Student stu2) {
                return stu1.getName().compareTo(stu2.getName());
            }
        });
        printCollection((Collection<Student>) customMap.get("NAME"));

    }

    // printing collection.
    private static void printCollection(Collection<Student> collection) {
        for (Student student : collection) {
            System.out.println(student.getId() + " : " + student.getName());
        }
        System.out.println("===end===");
    }
}
//dummy class whose list will be used.
class Student {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    public Student(Integer id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj != null && obj instanceof Student) {
            if (this.id == ((Student) obj).getId()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

you can directly execute above code. may be it can help you.